# iOS safari hitting onChange callback for input type datetime-local while selecting dates

Tags: html, jquery

I am using input type "datetime-local" field. It's working as expected on all browsers including android chrome, but in iOS safari it's hitting the **onChange** event while choosing the date rather then clicking on **Done** button.
Android chrome hits **onchange** event when we click on **Set** button.
I am submitting a form using **onChange** event. On safari, form gets submitted on selecting the new date without clicking on **Done** button.